# get all form inputs that are not in a particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I have a form like this

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div>
    <input type="text" name="input1" value="">
    <select name="my_list">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option> 
    </select>
    <textarea name="details"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="excluded">
    <input type="text" name="input2" value="">
    <input type="text" name="input2" value="">
    <input type="text" name="input3" value="">
    <textarea name="details2"></textarea>
</div>
</form>
```

I want to [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) all the inputs of my form but I want to exclude the inputs that are within the div with class **excluded**.

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
$('form').find(':input').not('.excluded').serialize();
```

Does anybody know how I can get all the form inputs that are not inside div with class **excluded** please?

Thank you

Comment: I think instead of `.not('.excluded')` try `.not('.excluded :input')`

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSS :not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

```
$('form div:not(.excluded) input').serialize();
```

```js
alert($('form div:not(.excluded) input').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
<div>
    <input type="text" name="input1" value="">
    <select name="my_list">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option> 
    </select>
    <textarea name="details"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="excluded">
    <input type="text" name="input2" value="">
    <input type="text" name="input2" value="">
    <input type="text" name="input3" value="">
    <textarea name="details2"></textarea>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Keep the `:input` so the `select` is included

Answer (score 0):

In `not()` you should using `.excluded :input` instead of `.excluded`.

```
$('form :input').not('.excluded :input').serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

First filter based on `div` then get all inputs form filtered result
some thing like

```
$('form').find("div").not('.excluded').find(':input').serialize();
```